# Feign encoder/decoder for Google Protocol Buffers

Tags: java, groovy, protocol-buffers, feign

I am using [Feign](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign) as a HTTP client. Now I am facing an API using [Google Protobuf](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/). Feign does not provide any encoder/decoder for Protobuf so it is necessary to implement custom ones.

```
import feign.RequestTemplate
import feign.codec.EncodeException
import feign.codec.Encoder

import java.lang.reflect.Type

class ProtobufEncoder implements Encoder {

    @Override
    void encode(Object object, Type bodyType, RequestTemplate template) throws EncodeException {
         // I am stuck here
    }
    
}
```

Someone solved this before?

Update: I am looking for a solution that uses plain Feign without Spring.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve protobuf encoding (described in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign/issues/442#issuecomment-267648233)) is to use `ProtobufHttpMessageConverter` class with `SpringEncoder` \ `SpringDecoder` from [spring-cloud-openfeign](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-openfeign) library.
In your application you need to configure the bean:

```
import org.springframework.http.converter.protobuf.ProtobufHttpMessageConverter;

@Configuration
public class ProtoBufConfig {
    @Autowired
    private ObjectFactory<HttpMessageConverters> messageConverters;
    
    @Bean
    ProtobufHttpMessageConverter protobufHttpMessageConverter() {
        return new ProtobufHttpMessageConverter();
    }

    //override the encoder
    @Bean
    public Encoder springEncoder(){
        return new SpringEncoder(this.messageConverters);
    }

    @Bean
    public Decoder springDecoder(){
        return new ResponseEntityDecoder(new SpringDecoder(this.messageConverters));
    }
}
```

And to you can use this configuration in the `FeignClient` annotation as such:

```
@FeignClient(name = "example-svc", configuration=ProtoBufConfig.class)
public interface KittensApiResource {

    @RequestMapping(value="/v1/api/kittens", method = RequestMethod.GET, consumes="application/x-protobuf", produces="application/x-protobuf")
    public ResponseEntity<KittenResponse> kittens();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I guess this way only works when soneone is using the Spring Framework.

Answer (score 0):

That is what I came up with. I also had to encode/decode with Base64 because it was required by the API I was working with.

Decoder:

```
@Slf4j
class ProtobufBase64Decoder implements Decoder {

    Map<Type, Message> protoMessagesCache = new HashMap<>()

    @Override
    Object decode(Response response, Type type) throws IOException, DecodeException, FeignException {
        if (response.body() == null) {
            return null
        }
        InputStream inputStream = BaseEncoding.base64().decodingStream(response.body().asReader(Charset.defaultCharset()))
        Message message = computeMessageForType(type)
        message.toBuilder().mergeFrom(inputStream).build()
    }

    private Message computeMessageForType(Type type) {
        if (!protoMessagesCache.containsKey(type)) {
                if (Message.class.isAssignableFrom(type)) {
                    Method builderMethod = type.getMethod("newBuilder")
                    Message message = ((Message.Builder) builderMethod.invoke(type)).getDefaultInstanceForType()
                    protoMessagesCache.put(type, message)
                } else {
                    throw new NoClassDefFoundError()
                }
        }
        protoMessagesCache.get(type)
    }

}
```

Encoder:

```
@Slf4j
class ProtobufBase64Encoder implements Encoder {

    @Override
    void encode(Object object, Type bodyType, RequestTemplate template) throws EncodeException {
        try {
            Message message = Message.cast(object)
            template.body(BaseEncoding.base64().encode(message.toByteArray()))
        } catch (ClassCastException ignored) {
            log.error("Unable to encode {} into protobuf", object)
        }
    }

}
```